# How to apply a modeline added to an unnamed buffer?

Tags: modeline

I have the following workflow:

- Create a new unnamed buffer with `:enew`
- Use a snippet to add a modeline to it. E.g. `vim:tw=80:ft=text:spell`

Once I've done that the modeline isn't applied and I can't do `:e %` to reload
the buffer and apply the modeline since it is an unnamed buffer.

What can I do to apply the modeline in this unnamed buffer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the [`:h auto-setting`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#auto%2Dsetting) help file, you will see that the options are set on different occasions:

1. At initialization
2. On autocommands
3. When starting editing the file with the modeline on

You can reload the modeline without actually reloading the buffer by calling manually an autocommand:

```
:doautocmd BufRead
```

This will reload your modeline without reloading your file.

Of course, you need to have set `modeline` prior to this (otherwise the modeline won't be used).

Reference: [`:h :doautocmd`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#%3Adoautocmd).

**Note**: if you want to actually execute an autocommand without reloading the modeline, you can pass the `<nomodeline>` to the `doautocmd` method.